# How to Reload a Python Module? Clearing Variable Info

Tags: python, python-module

I've been storing variable information inside the builtins module and I want to clear all the variable information that is stored inside of it. I can't figure out how to do it though.

```
import importlib
import builtins
print("add" in dir(builtins))
builtins.add = "x"
print("add" in dir(builtins))
importlib.reload(builtins)
print("add" in dir(builtins))
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: "I've been storing variable information inside the builtins module" - jesus crap, ***why***?

Comment: `builtins` is not a normal module. It's loaded as part of the core interpreter; I doubt `reload` actually does anything meaningful for it.

Comment: BTW, per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload): "It is generally not very useful to reload built-in or dynamically loaded modules. Reloading `sys`, `__main__`, `builtins` and other key modules is not recommended. In many cases extension modules are not designed to be initialized more than once, and may fail in arbitrary ways when reloaded."

Comment: @user2357112 Yea, I realize what I am doing is not conventional. I am supplying a builtins module to a dictionary that is being passed into the global_env parameter of an exec function. Code from the exec function stores its global variables inside of builtins module naturally and I want a clean copy of the builtins module.

Comment: @btomtom5: Okay, you're not making this seem any more sane. `exec`-ed code that stores to `builtins` on purpose? WTF?!? If it's just assigning values to its own globals, just create a new `dict` and then pass a reference to it to `exec` to populate, don't pollute the namespace of every Python module to do something terrible.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I feel like I have justified reason to do this. I am serializing many different types of python objects using the dill module except dill relies on the builtins to get class definitions. So when I try copying an object defined inside an exec function from outside the exec functions environment, I have to define the object twice. Once inside the builtins module and another time normally. After the object is copied, I clear the builtins module. But sometimes my program crashes before I can clean up after myself and I need a clean slate which is why I need to "reload' builtins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reload` does not clear a module's `__dict__` before reloading it, so reloading a module doesn't affect any names you add to it that weren't originally part of the module.

It is essentially always better to avoid messing with the `builtins` module than to try to restore it after messing with it. That said, if you really want to do this, save a copy of `builtins.__dict__` before messing with it so you can restore from the backup later:

```
# Before screwing with builtins:
builtins_backup = builtins.__dict__.copy()

# After screwing with builtins:
builtins.__dict__.clear()
builtins.__dict__.update(builtins_backup)
```

That's not going to be threadsafe if another thread comes in between the `clear` and the `update`, but trying to reload `builtins` is hardly in safe territory anyway.

Comment: aah this makes sense. I appreciate this a lot! That being said, this does seem incredibly unstable and seems like bad practice as you suggested. I will use this to front functionality for now before I come up with a more stable solution.